# Does corr function in Matlab consider correction for tied ranks?

Tags: correlation, matlab, ties

Does 'corr' function in Matlab consider correction for tied ranks while calculating Spearman correlation coefficient?
Thanks.

Comment: The easy way to find out is to feed it some simple datasets having ties!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking in the `corr` function, I see that it calls `tiedrank`:

```
$ grep -B 1 tiedrank corr.m
      case 'k' % Kendall's tau
          [xrank, xadj] = tiedrank(xi,1);
          [yrank, yadj] = tiedrank(yj,1);
--
       case 's' % Spearman's rank correlation
          [xrank, xadj] = tiedrank(xi,0);
          [yrank, yadj] = tiedrank(yj,0);
```

Issuing a `help tiedrank` in Matlab should help you further along.